# How to transfer records from cassettes to the computer?

Tags: home-studio

I have a walkman with a lot of cassettes (TDK D-C60 cassette) - some of the records that I made back in 80's - can anyone, please, recommend a software for transferring all those records from cassettes to the computer.

Comment: Didn't you try Google first? I find [Tutorial - Copying tapes, LPs or MiniDiscs to CD](https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/tutorial_copying_tapes_lps_or_minidiscs_to_cd.html) easily.

Comment: @U.Windl - LOL! I asked that question 10 years ago. That Audacity tutorial might have not even existed then.

Comment: But obviously the question is still being read, to the comment may be useful for current readers.

Comment: @U.Windl - Yes, you are right. I agree with you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An example of a specialized software to record LPs and cassettes

- [LP Ripper (commercial)](http://www.cfbsoftware.com/lpripper/lpripper.aspx):

Optional any software that can record the line input will do, for example:

- [Audacity (free)](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/) (see also [this link for instructions](https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/splitting_a_recording_into_separate_tracks.html) on how-to)
- [GoldWave (shareware)](http://www.goldwave.com/)

Record the whole side and then go in a chop up into segments, and save out.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Ken's excellent answer, [Ion Audio](http://www.ionaudio.com/) do a range of products for LP, tape and VHS that plug directly into a USB port on your computer and use Audacity.

The advantage here is that they sort out normalisation and EQ automatically, and in the case of the VHS tapes, they cope with various versions of PAL, NTSC etc.

Their LP decks are pretty awesome:

[image]